# Show that $\left( \frac {11} {10}\right) ^{n}$ is divergent.

Tags: analysis, limits, proof-verification, divergence-operator

> Show that $\left( \dfrac {11} {10}\right) ^{n}$ is divergent.

**My proof.** Let $B\in\mathbb{R}$. By the Archimedean property there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $N>B$.
   Let $\varepsilon >0$ By the Bernoulli inequality, we have $\left( 1+\varepsilon \right) ^{n}\geq 1+n\varepsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, take $\varepsilon=( \dfrac {11} {10}-1)$. Then, we obtain, $\left( \dfrac {11} {10}\right) ^{n}\geq \dfrac {n} {10}+1$. So, for all $n\geq N$ we have $\dfrac {n} {10}+1>\dfrac {n} {10}>n>N>B.$ Thus, since $\left( \dfrac {11} {10}\right) ^{n}\geq \dfrac {n} {10}+1$,  $\left( \dfrac {11} {10}\right) ^{n}>B$
for all $n\geq N$.

We are done.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: $\frac{n}{10} > n?$

Comment: Perhaps better to say $\frac{n}{10} > N > B$ when $n > 10N$, in which case $\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^n > B$

Comment: Please replace the incorrect `Show that lim x_n is divergent` by `Show that (x_n) is divergent` or, but this is not as good, `Show that lim x_n = +oo`.

Comment: I don't see the point of the separate N and B, and saying "let epsilon > 0" seems misplaced - you are really just invoking Bernoulli's inequality, and you just want to say it holds for all epsilon and n. (If you first say "let epsilon > 0" then you should not choose a specific epsilon afterwards.)

Comment: @SahibaArora Hah! Yes!. Sorry.

Comment: The bound of 11/10 ^n is the bound of 11/10 ^(n+1). Thus the bound is 11/10 times itself. Since we know it is not less than or equal to 0, it must be infinity.

Answer (score 4):

The error in your proof is the assertion $$\frac{n}{10}>n$$ This is not true as $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

In the comments, Henry suggests how your proof can be fixed.

> An alternate way to prove the sequence is divergent is to show that it is unbounded.

It follows by Bernoulli's inequality that $$\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{10}\right)^n\geq1+\frac{n}{10}>\frac{n}{10}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$
Hence, the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: This is in fact the essence of the OP's almost correct proof, cleaned up so that it can be expressed in one or two lines. +1 for the nice editing.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to think solution:

Note that $\ln$ is increasing function.

Note that $\ln\Big(\dfrac{11}{10}\Big)=\ln11-\ln10=c>0$

Now $\ln\Big(\dfrac{11}{10}\Big)^n=n(\ln11-\ln10)=nc$

Now since $c>0$, for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $N>\Big\lfloor\dfrac{1}{c}\Big\rfloor+1$, you can find a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $nc>N$. Hence $\ln\Big(\dfrac{11}{10}\Big)^n$ diverges to infinity. Since $\ln$ is increasing function $\Big(\dfrac{11}{10}\Big)^n$ also diverges to infinity.